# Minecraft 1.4.6 Force Update Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just bought Minecraft and suddenly my whole Minecraft folder inside is gone; nothing except saves. I tried to `Force Update` but it said `Not Downloaded`. I downgraded to Snapshot 12w50a/12w50b, and I still get the error `Not Downloaded`. I installed LWJGL, but it's still not working. I'm using OS X 10.8.3.

Comment: Stupid question, but are you using a cracked client or an account not paid for?

Answer (score 1):

Go to C:/Users//AppData/Roaming/.minecraft
(You must enable hidden files before doing this.)

Cut the folders "saves", "screenshots", "stats", "texturepacks", "servers.dat", and options.txt".

Make a new folder, and paste all the cut folders/files into this new folder. (This is to backup your worlds/screenshots, etc)

Delete everything else. [Download Minecraft.exe](https://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftDownload/launcher/Minecraft_Server.exe) from [www.minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/download) and run it. Now go to your backup folder you made, and cut/paste those files/folders into C:/Users..../.minecraft

If something says "Do you want to merge these files?" Say yes.
If something says "Do you want to overwrite/replace these files?" Say yes.

Hopefully, you will have copied your worlds/screenshots/etc, re-installed Minecraft, and put your worlds/screenshots/etc back into your Minecraft game.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once, although it wasn't exactly the same. It seemed to be that when Minecraft said: `not downloaded`, it means that the Minecraft.net servers were down. Once they came back up, I deleted the application and re-downloaded it, and it installed fine.

Comment: you can check the various servers' status at http://help.mojang.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, check the [Minecraft server's status](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/). If it still persists and the servers are good, then follow [these instructions](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gDRbA6g2) to set up the pure Java-based launcher and try it. Hope this helps!