# My minecraft won't update to 1.4.6

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minecraft 1.4.6 Force Update Problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97597/minecraft-1-4-6-force-update-problem)

I can't update to 1.4.6. I go into minecraft and hit login and it says login failed. When I play offline it doesn't update. I've tried using force update. Help!