# Minecraft Force Update Problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minecraft 1.4.6 Force Update Problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97597/minecraft-1-4-6-force-update-problem)

In Minecraft 1.4.6 I wanted to download a mod so I did force update. I checked back in the file but the other normal files weren't there. I downloaded the mod anyways (Too Many Items) But it didn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: The only information you've provided is that the mod didn't work; I suspect there might be two different issues in play here; the force update, and the mod not working.  The force update issue has already been asked (http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97597/minecraft-1-4-6-force-update-problem), and we need more information to answer the mod question.

Comment: What do you mean by "the other normal files weren't there"? What files? Where?